# Yii2: How add a symbol before and after an input field

Tags: php, html, css, yii2

How can I add a symbol before and after of an input text? Just like the image attach.

[image]

My code:

```
<?= $form->field($model_product, 'percent')->textInput(['class'=>'smallInputFormInline'])->label('Percent',['class'=>'labelModalFormInline']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model_product, 'percent_all')->textInput(['class'=>'smallInputFormInline'])->label('Percent All',['class'=>'labelModalFormInline']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model_product, 'amount')->textInput(['class'=>'smallInputFormInline'])->label('Amount',['class'=>'labelModalFormInline']) ?>
```

**SOLUTION**

I modify my code following ActiveForm documentation and it works!

Code modified:

```
<?= $form->field($model_product, 'amount', ['template' => '{label}${input}'])->textInput(['class'=>'smallInputFormInline'])->label('Amount',['class'=>'labelModalFormInline']) ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example you can add some addons to input using ActiveForm field `"template"` option.

E.g. `%` addon at the end of input:

```
<?= $form->field($model_product, 'percent', [
            'template' => '{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}<div class="input-group">{input}
            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span></div>{error}{hint}'
        ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo classes we can do.

```css
.input-symbol {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
.input-symbol:before {
  content: "\0024";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  
}
.input-symbol:after {
  content: "\0024";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-symbol">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Appreciate if it is useful :)