# How to append serial number in activeForm form attribute

Tags: yii2

Trying to display questions from table, I want display serial number before that question.

I tried but I am getting number in one line and question is other line.

EX: 
[image]

```
<?= $index+1 . $form->field($practiceTest, "[$index]question")->textarea(['readonly'=> true]) ?>
```

Can any one give an idea how to display number after question like. 

Ex: 1. question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: How add a symbol before and after an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140005/yii2-how-add-a-symbol-before-and-after-an-input-field)

Comment: use the `template` option inside the `field()` options parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Ordered List in case when you need to get numbers calculated.

```
<ol type="1">
  <!-- I guess here you iterate to get index -->
  <li>
      <?= $form->field($practiceTest, "[$index]question")->textarea(['readonly'=> true]) ?>
  </li>

 <!-- Finish iteration -->
</ol>
```

Hope it will helps